# Firebase OpenID Connect creates user after login with Twitch Auth. but leaves Identifier empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, openid-connect, twitch

I am trying to make users login with their Twitch account using OpenID Connect.

So far, you can login by logging in with Twitch, but Firebase creates a user with an empty Identifier where normally your email would be (when logging in with Google)

[see created user in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Enpu.png)

Am I missing any steps?

Here is how I handle the Twitch Login using Firebase OpenID Connect.

```
// TWITCH SIGN IN HANDLER
const twitchsigninBtn = document.getElementById('twitchsigninBtn');

var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('oidc.twitch');

// Twitch Custom Parameters:
provider.setCustomParameters({
        // Target specific email with login hint.
        force_verify: 'true'
      });

// Twitch Login function
twitchsigninBtn.onclick = () => {

// let firebase handle the entire login flow!
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // IdP data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile.
    // ...

    /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
    var credential = result.credential;

    // OAuth access and id tokens can also be retrieved:
    var accessToken = credential.accessToken;
    var idToken = credential.idToken;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error.
  });

}
```

And in Firebase OIDC setup, I've set the Issuer (URL): https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the claims within `provider.setCustomParameters`, it required the email to be added to the user database.

```js
provider.setCustomParameters({
        // Target specific email with login hint.
        force_verify: 'true',
        claims: '{"userinfo":{"email":null,"email_verified":null,"picture":null,"updated_at":null}}'
      });
```